# What is the PDO statements equivalent?

Tags: php

I have this code which uses `mysql_query` which is deprecated so please tell me what the equivalent PDO code for these lines:

```
$rs = mysql_query('select * from locations');
$result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
    array_push($result, $row);
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. If you want to add WHERE clause you can give parameters in $query_args array.

```html
$sql = "SELECT * from locations";

    $query_args = array(
        
    );
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_args);
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
        $response["details"] = $ex;
    }
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the equivalent.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from locations");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

if ($result) {
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

connect.php

```
<?php
function getConnection(){
$dbhost= "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass="";
$dbname="table";
$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8');
$dsn = "mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8";
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass,$options);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
```

file.php

```
require "connect.php";
$pdo = getConnection();
$dbh->prepare("SEELCT * FROM locations;");
$dbh->execute();
$result = $dbh->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`
```